# Monthly report for C# application

Tags: c#

I am building a report for my application using VS2010.

The data for the application is stored in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

The columns are

```
DateCreated (DateTime)
CardPrinted (bit)
DatePrinted(DateTime)
```

I want to create a report that will show, for each month starting from January 2012,

1. Total Number of `CardPrinted` for week1
2. Total Number of `CardPrinted` for week2
3. Total Number of `CardPrinted` for week3
4. Total Number of `CardPrinted` for week 4

NB: If a card is printed, it is Marks 1 in the database, so that the `CardPrinted`
column is either 1 or 0.

Please I need someone to to help with the query I needed to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Show us your efforts - we'll help, but we won't just write the whole query for you.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a start

```
Select DATEPART ( week , DatePrinted) as WeekNo, Count(*) as TotalNumberPrinted
From SomeTable 
Where CardPrinted = 1
And DatePrinted >= '2012-01-01'
Group by DATEPART ( week , DatePrinted)
```

Comment: Should that `2012-12-01` be `2012-01-01`? That seems to be filtering for stuff printed from december 2012 onwards (which I suspect will be sparese :)).

Comment: Glad someone's got this attention to detail thing sorted. Edited to correct

Comment: I find one of the most educational parts of stack overflow is looking at other people's answers and making sure I know what they are doing (and why) so I quite often find myself making sure that answers work. Sometimes (in less obvious cases than this) I'll ask a question and find that I'm wrong and learn something exciting and new. :) Sometimes its just neat tricks that I might not have thought of (like grouping by datepart here).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tony Hopkinson.
After little modification i got the it right.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,DatePrinted)AS Month_of_year,
DATEPART(WEEK,DatePrinted) AS Weeks, COUNT(*) AS No_ofCardprinted
From  MyTable
Where CardPrinted = 1 and DateCreated between DATEADD(Day, - 61, GETDATE())  
and DATEADD(Day, -0, GETDATE())
Group by DATEPART (WEEK , DatePrinted), DATEPART(MONTH,DatePrinted)
order by Month_of_year ASC
```

Comment: You should accept his answer then. It gives him points in this website and helps others having similar problems.